# Dynamically create rows in a table based on condition in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am passing a set of controls(checkbox,radio buttons etc) as a list through controller to its corresponding view. Here is what I want to achieve.

1. Each row in the table should have 3 columns.
2. If the number of objects are more than 3 then a new row should be created in the table.

I am doing this using MVC 4.

Comment: In addition to posting your requirements you forgot to show what you have tried so far and what difficulties did you encounter with your code. Right now you sound more like a customer in a restaurant than a software developer asking a specific programming related question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way yo can do it in mvc :

Model:

```
    public class Class1
    {
          public string numbers { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller code :

```
    public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
            //Sample1--load array data using linq
            List<Class1> model = new List<Class1>();
            int[] numbersdata = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0, 15, 14, 11, 13, 19, 18, 16, 17, 12, 10 };

            var lowNums = from n in numbersdata where n > 5 select n;

            foreach (var x in lowNums)
            {
                model.Add(new Class1()
                {
                    numbers = x.ToString()
                });
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

view :

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Class1>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table width="960px">
        <tr>
            @{
    int crow = 1;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;" width="600px">
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                        <li>
                            @Html.TextBox("txt")
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </td>
        if (crow % 3 == 0)
        {                                                    
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 285px; height: 50px">
                    </td>
                </tr>
        }
        crow++;
        }
     }
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```